# Cannot find configuration node with WFFM

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to upgrade our Web Forms For Marketers to the latest available on SDN, however when I come to install I get the follow exception throw:

```
Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='production']
```

However, this is correct so far as the only databases configured are Core, Master and Web.

I tried adding a production node (pointing to Master) to Databases.config/ConnectionStrings.config however it still throws this error.

Has anyone encountered this and has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with a bug in Sitecore not correctly cleaning and rebuilding the Links database.

Sitecore Support provided this solution:

1. Back up.
2. Truncate the links table in the Core database.
3. Rebuild Link Database from the Sitecore Control Panel.

This seemed to solve the issue in the short term. I'm sure it'll be addressed in a Sitecore update in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you it cannot find a `<database>` node in your `web.config` for "production" so you'll need to have that. Something you have must be referencing that.