# Sitecore is throwing a database node exception in the CD environment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, goal-tracking

WFFM works great in the CM environment.

In the CD environment, I unpacked the content inside of `Web Forms for Marketers CD 8.2 rev. 161129.zip` in my `Website` folder. I then:

1. On all the CD servers, in the `\Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Forms.Config` file, remove or disable the following sections. `<hook type="Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionHook, Sitecore.Forms.Core"/>`
2. Removed the `<event name="wffm:action:remote">` section as well.
3. I added `<setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true" />` and `<setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="true" />`.

In my `connectionstrings.config`, there is no connection name for `master`. We've decided to remove all references to `master` in the CD environment.

In the showconfig file, I see `<setting name="WFM.MasterDatabase" value="web" patch:source="Sitecore.Forms.config" />`.

I published the entire site from CM to CD. When I look at the page in the CD environment, I get the following exception:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String format, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.Data.ItemDb.GoalDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecord
Mapper`1 mapper)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Goals.Data.ItemDb.GoalDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive)
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469286/cannot-find-configuration-node-with-wffm), I truncated the `links` table in the Core database, and rebuilt it again. Still, no luck!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going back and forth with Sitecore Support, they noted that this issue is not related to WFFM, but to the Goals definitions that cannot be loaded.

**Response from Sitecore**

> The issue that SwitchMasterToWeb config leaves a reference to the Master database in  node  was registered as a bug in our bug tracking system. 
>   To track the future status of this bug report, please use the reference number 98770

**Important**

> Make sure the following changes are made **ONLY** in the CD environment(s).

Open `\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.config`, and change the followings:
from `<itemRepositoriesDatabase>master</itemRepositoriesDatabase>` to `<itemRepositoriesDatabase>web</itemRepositoriesDatabase>`

Doing so, will cause a `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException` exception. Stack trace will include:

```
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Exceptions.IndexNotFoundException
Message: Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(String name)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Search.BaseDefinitionSearchProvider`2..ctor(String indexName)
```

According to [this article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_indexes_required_in_a_scalable_environment), `sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master` index should not be present on CD. To fix this issue, open `\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Marketing.Search.config`, and change the following:
from `<searchIndexName>sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master</searchIndexName>` to `<searchIndexName>sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web</searchIndexName>`

Answer (score 1):

Hit /admin/showconfig.aspx or use SIM to make a config xml and look for "master".  You should not have any.  Wherever it is, check the patch source and write a patch for that file.  Maybe put it in Switchtomaster.config.

Comment: There is 0 reference to `master` in the sowconfig file. Also, the only reference to it in `SwitchToMaster` is the delete patch.